# How do I store data in a function from a loop?

Tags: python, calculator

I'm planning to make a vector calculator and I wanted to make the program more efficient. Is there any way that the data inputted from a previous loop cycle not be lost so that I can summate them? For example, the program asks me to input a value for Magnitude, after the loop cycle and it asks me again for a value for Magnitude, I don't want to lose the first value that I've inputted so that I can summate them after.
Here is the program:

````
import math
from ctypes import *

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD (Structure):
    pass

COORD._fields_=[("X",c_short),("Y",c_short)]

def print_at(r, c, s):
    h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, COORD(c, r))

    c = s.encode("windows-1252")
    windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleA(h, c_char_p(c), len(c), None, None)

def Compute():
    if Direction == "NofE" or Direction == "NofW" or Direction == "SofW" or Direction == "SofE":
        xComp1 = round(Force * (math.degrees(math.cos(Angle))), 3)
        yComp1 = round(Force * (math.degrees(math.sin(Angle))), 3)
    elif Direction == "EofN" or Direction == "WofN" or Direction == "WofS" or Direction == "EofS":
        yComp1 = round(Force * (math.degrees(math.cos(Angle))), 3)
        xComp1 = round(Force * (math.degrees(math.sin(Angle))), 3)
    print_at(4, 95, str(xComp1))
    print(4, 110, str(yComp1))


## main program ##

while True:

    _=os.system("cls")
    print_at(1, 0, "Directions: NofE, NofW, SofW, SofE, EofN, WofN, WofS, EofS \n")
    print_at(3, 55, "Magnitude")
    print_at(3, 70, "Direction")
    print_at(3, 85, "Angle")
    print_at(3, 95, "X-Component")
    print_at(3, 110, "Y-Component \n")

    Force = float(input("\n Force: "))
    print_at(4, 55, str(Force))

    if Force == 0:
        break

    Angle = float(input("\n Angle: "))
    print_at(4, 85, str(Angle))

    Direction = (input("\n Direction: "))
    print_at(4, 70, str(Direction))
    Compute()


    Continue = input("\n Do you want to continue?(Y/N)")
    if Continue == "Y" or Continue == "y":
        continue

    elif Continue == "N" or Continue == "n":
        break

    else:
        print ("Answer not recognized.")```
````

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that asks for a value for Magnitude, only something that writes "Magnitude" on the screen. Did you mean `Force`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#The way you did, you already have the value saved, it is lost just when you type again, 
#you can try this code by using lists types, focus on the Force in code, and try to see how it works:

import os
import math
from ctypes import *

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

class COORD (Structure):
    pass

COORD._fields_=[("X",c_short),("Y",c_short)]

def print_at(r, c, s):
    h = windll.kernel32.GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    windll.kernel32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, COORD(c, r))

    c = s.encode("windows-1252")
    windll.kernel32.WriteConsoleA(h, c_char_p(c), len(c), None, None)

def Compute():
    direct1=["NofE","NofW","SofW","SofE"]
    direct2=["EofN","WofN","WofS","EofS"]
    if Direction in direct1:
        xComp1 = round(Force[a] * (math.degrees(math.cos(Angle))), 3)
        yComp1 = round(Force[a] * (math.degrees(math.sin(Angle))), 3)
    elif Direction in direct2:
        yComp1 = round(Force[a] * (math.degrees(math.cos(Angle))), 3)
        xComp1 = round(Force[a] * (math.degrees(math.sin(Angle))), 3)
    try:
        print_at(4, 95, str(xComp1))
        print(4, 110, str(yComp1))
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass


## main program ##
Force=[]
a=0
while True:
    _=os.system("cls")
    print_at(1, 0, "Directions: NofE, NofW, SofW, SofE, EofN, WofN, WofS, EofS \n")
    print_at(3, 55, "Magnitude")
    print_at(3, 70, "Direction")
    print_at(3, 85, "Angle")
    print_at(3, 95, "X-Component")
    print_at(3, 110, "Y-Component \n")
    try:
        Force.append(float(input("\n Force: ")))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    print_at(4, 55, str(Force))

    if Force == 0:
        break
    try:
        Angle = float(input("\n Angle: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    print_at(4, 85, str(Angle))

    Direction = (input("\n Direction: "))
    print_at(4, 70, str(Direction))
    Compute()


    Continue = input("\n Do you want to continue?(Y/N)")
    if Continue == "Y" or Continue == "y":
        continue

    elif Continue == "N" or Continue == "n":
        break

    else:
        print ("Answer not recognized.")
    a+=1
```